# show linked files in autodesk forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

i am trying to make auto-desk forge viewer.
using this link [Forge & ASP.NET: from zero to hero in 30 minutes](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-aspnet-zero-hero-30-minutes)

and it works fine with single revit file.

now i want to view revit document that has linked document and i found this post [How to Set References with Revit Files for View and Data API](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/07/how-to-set-references-with-revit-files-for-view-and-data-api.html)

but i think it is an old version of api.
so i don't know how to apply these steps in the viewer code.
any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A zipped file which is contained the host RVT file and corresponding linked files can help you archive this goal. After uploading this ZIP file to the Forge DM, you have to make sure that ‘compressedUrn: true’ and ‘rootFilename: {your host RVT filename with the sub filename .rvt}’ your input field of the job configuration body while submitting your translation job. Please refer here for the details: https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/

Answer (score 0):

Some more info:

1. If you do not want to manage the reference, while simply count on Forge detects the reference automatically, the choice is what Eason mentioned: package all files in an zip, upload, and ask Forge Post Job service to translate the zip. You only need to specify the root file.
   https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/
   This blog tells more:
   https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/07/translate-referenced-files-by-derivative-api.html
2. If you want to manage the reference, e.g. in one time, you have uploaded all files of one version or only a few files of the package. While after some time, some files need to be updated, or are not referred anymore, but it is unnecessary to upload all related files again (as in #1, upload zip again). 
   In such scenario, the choice is, firstly, set reference manually by another Forge service (Set Reference):
   https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-references-POST/
   next, ask POST Job service to translate:
   https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/

Answer (score 0):

As of 1/2020 Autodesk has said that they do not support reference endpoint when exporting to SVG so zip file is the only supported method currenty.