# Linked Revit files are not shown in Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm making job to translate rvt to svf2 using Model Derivative API.

The Revit file contains links to many Revit files, so I upload a zip file containing the root and linked files and create a job for translate by referring to [Upload linked Revit models for Forge Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49142842/upload-linked-revit-models-for-forge-viewer) and [show linked files in autodesk forge viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49649794/show-linked-files-in-autodesk-forge-viewer).

My job's config contains two additional parameters: compressedUrn and rootFilename, but I am not able to get the views that have models in the linked Revit files.

The root file is associated with the linked files with relative paths in Revit.

What could be the reason why it doesn't work?

Comment: Hi MASAMIKI-san. Could you share a snapshot of your [Revit's Manage Link](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2023/ENU/Revit-Collaborate/files/GUID-C7094D06-D4C5-4CCB-8E7B-5C8188EC3272-htm.html) dialog for the host model and your model URN encountering this issue?

Comment: BTW, The linked models cannot be put in a folder within the ZIP.

Comment: @EasonKang
Thnak you for your reply. Through trial and error, I've just identified the cause. It seems that the cause was that the file name of the linked Revit was in Japanese. (I think it's because of multibyte characters.) I changed the file name to English, relinked the link, and reuploaded the zipped file. Is there a way to deal with multi-byte characters in linked file names?

Comment: MASAMIKI-san, thanks for sharing your investigation results. If so, it sounds like an issue for the Model Derivative service. Could you consider providing a reproducible case containing the host and links encountering this issue to `asp [DOT] help [AT] autodesk [DOT] com`? No need to provide the whole model. Just remain a few elements inside the RVT, but keep the link relationships with the filename in Japanese. I will help pass the test case to our engineering team for investigation.

Comment: @EasonKang
I tried to send email `asp [DOT] help [AT] autodesk [DOT] com`, but the email was rejected. Do you have other emails?

Comment: MASAMIKI-san, my apologies for the typo. It should be `aps (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`

Comment: MASAMIKI-san, I submitted an issue report RVTLMV-3162 on your behalf.